# Why doesn't it work I'm trying to make a simple calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

print("choose 1 to add and 2 to subtract")
select = input("enter choice 1/2")

a = float(input("enter 1st nunber: "))
b = float(input("enter 2nd number: "))

if select == 1:
    print(a, "+", b, "=", add(a, b))
```

I don't know why it doesn't wanna add

Comment: `input()` returns a string.  `select = input("enter choice 1/2")` The variable `select` is therefore a string.  `if select == 1` will never be true because `1` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `select` variable to integer. By default, the input is taken as string value. You can also use f-string [(see more at Formatted String Literals documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) for printing values from variables in the print statement which gives you much more flexibility to format the string:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b


print("choose 1 to add and 2 to subtract")
select = int(input("enter choice 1/2: "))
a = float(input("enter 1st nunber: "))
b = float(input("enter 2nd number: "))
if select == 1:
    print(f"{a} + {b} = {add(a, b)}")
```

Output:

```
choose 1 to add and 2 to subtract
enter choice 1/2: 1
enter 1st nunber: 21
enter 2nd number: 3
21.0 + 3.0 = 24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `select` into an `int`

```py
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

print("choose 1 to add and 2 to subtract")
select = int(input("enter choice 1/2"))

a = float(input("enter 1st nunber: "))
b = float(input("enter 2nd number: "))

if select == 1:
    print(a, "+", b, "=", add(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string, but in the line `if select == 1` you are comparing it to an `int`. There are several solutions to this, but the solution I would go with is to use only strings, i.e. `if select == "1"`. `1` and `2` are arbitrary values, so it isn't really necessary for them to be converted to numbers. You could just as easily use `a` and `b` to accomplish the same goal.

Another useful thing you can do is validate the user input. I would do that with something like this:

```
while select not in ["1", "2"]:
    print(f"you entered {select}, which is not a valid option")
    select = input("enter choice 1/2")
```

This will continue to ask the user to select one of the choices until they enter a valid one, and also has the added bonus of helping you catch errors in your code like the `int` vs `str` issue.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, since input returns a `str`, it should be compared with an object of same type. Just changing `1` to `str(1)` on line 10 will solve the issue.

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

print("choose 1 to add and 2 to subtract")
select = input("enter choice 1/2")

a = float(input("enter 1st nunber: "))
b = float(input("enter 2nd number: "))

if select == str(1):
    print(a, "+", b, "=", add(a, b))
```